# moving one value form list to another delete next value from list

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have two listboxes when i swap value to another listbox it always remove next value from the list and when i try to swap last value from the list it take top one value form the list . I try to find the problem but i don't get any result. Below is the code part for review.

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox lstEmployeelist, ListBox lstSelectedEmployees)
{
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = lstEmployeelist.SelectedItems;
    List<Master> newsource = this.masterBindingSource.DataSource as List<Master>;
    List<Master> _selectedSource = this.masterSellectedBindingSource.DataSource as List<Master>;

    try
    {
        if (lstEmployeelist.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sourceItems.Count -1 ; i++)
            {
                Master item = sourceItems[i] as Master;
                this.masterSellectedBindingSource.AddNew();
                Master sitems = masterSellectedBindingSource.Current as Master;
                sitems.Empno = item.Empno;
                sitems.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                newsource.Remove((Master)item);
            }

            if (sourceItems.Count > 0)
                this.masterBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();

            this.masterSellectedBindingSource.EndEdit();
            lstSelectedEmployees.DataSource = masterSellectedBindingSource;
            lstSelectedEmployees.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
            lstSelectedEmployees.ValueMember = "Empno";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is with the way you iterate through sourceItems.

Because you are doing it using a for loop (presumably because you cannot do it with a foreach because you cant then modify the collection), when you remove say item 1 from the collection and add it to the 2nd list, item 2 and all items after move up 1.

So item 2 becomes the new item 1 and item 3 becomes item 2, etc, etc...

To fix this, when you decide to move an item you also need to decrease i by 1 (i--;) so that when the for loops round again and i is increased it is back to the same index.

---

IF you are moving ALL items and not only select items, then you should not use a for loop, use a while instead like this:

```
while (sourceItems.Count > 0)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: what happen when the user select more than one item from the list ?

Comment: @a-goutam I dont quite understand what you mean? If you are dealing with selected items in a list then you would iterate through the equivalent SelectedItems collection or iterate through every item checking if it was selected and moving as required.

Your code doesn't really demonstrate what you are doing very well.

Comment: i want that when user select one value from the list that will remove from current list and the sellected item will dispaly in second list